# SHA-1 base32 of a file report back to a string

Tags: php

I'm having troubles figuring out how to implement a program that I can generate a base32 sha-1 value of a file.  I know it can't be too difficult to figure out as to generate a standard sha1 file is fairly easy.

```
$file1 = sha1_file('main.jpg');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: PHP doesn't have built-in base32 support.  You're gonna have to find a class to do it for you.  I made a (crappy) one: https://github.com/NTICompass/PHP-Base32  You can probably find a better one if you Google around, though.

Comment: sha1_file is a hashing function it is not reversable. It is one way encryption.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It does: [`base_convert`](http://php.net/base_convert).

Comment: @RocketHazmat Unfortunately, PHP uses integers or some other limited data type internally so that you can’t convert arbitrary large values.

Comment: @Gumbo: Depending on whether you base 32 the hex data, the binary data, or convert the hex to a base32 number, you get different answers:  http://ideone.com/nKHwOy  (Done in python to make things easier).  Seems one is "encoding" and the other is "converting".

Comment: I have tested the php script against a base 32 calculator and they are different results. I will share the code I have thus far.

Comment: <?php
$hex = sha1_file('main.jpg');
$base32 = base_convert($hex, 16, 32);
$mapping = array_combine(array_merge(range('0','9'),range('a','z')), array_merge(range('A','Z'),range('0','9')));
$base32 = strtr($base32, $mapping);
echo "$base32";
rename('main.jpg', $base32) or die("Unable to rename.");
?>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encode the SHA1 value as Base32, you gonna have to either write that yourself or find a library.  PHP does not have it built-in, like it does with `base64_encode`.

A while ago, I needed a `base32_encode` function, so I wrote one.  I don't know how efficient it is, and I'm sure better ones exist out there, but it does work.  It's located here: https://github.com/NTICompass/PHP-Base32

Using that you can do:

```
<?php
include 'Base32.php';

$base32 = new Base32;

$file1 = sha1_file('main.jpg');
echo $base32->base32_encode($file1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm getting different return results when I compare the values from the php program to a hash calculator.  I will keep playing around and see what I can come up with.

Comment: What hash calculator are you using, just out of curiosity?

Comment: fsum frontend from sourceforge

Comment: Does that give you base32, or are you using another tool to encode?

Answer (score 0):

I have a PHP class, [Base2n](https://github.com/ademarre/binary-to-text-php), which can encode Base32 per RFC 4648. It's actually more flexible than that, allowing you to parametrically define many standard and non-standard encoding schemes with a 2<sup>n</sup> base.

https://github.com/ademarre/binary-to-text-php

Base32 is demonstrated in the first example of the README file.

Here's what your "main.jpg" example would look like:

```
// include, require, or autoload Base2n

$file1 = sha1_file('main.jpg', TRUE);

$base32 = new Base2n(5, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567', FALSE, TRUE, TRUE);
$base32FileHash = $base32->encode($file1);
```

Notice that I also set `$raw_output=TRUE` in the call to `sha1_file()`. I assume this is what you want because otherwise the Base32 output would be done on the hexadecimal representation of the SHA-1 hash digest, not the raw 160-bit digest itself.